# New York Times news scraping using pure python and selenium(via rpaframework)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, rpa

Im trying to scrap New York Times search result using pure python and selenium(via rpaframework) but I'm not getting it correct. I need to get the title, date, and description. Here is my code so far

When I print the title I'm getting this error

**selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: unknown variant `//h4[@class='css-2fgx4k']`, expected one of `css selector`, `link text`, `partial link text`, `tag name`, `xpath` at line 1 column 37**

```
from RPA.Browser.Selenium import Selenium

# Search term
search_term = "climate change"

# Open the NY Times search page and search for the term
browser = Selenium()
browser.open_available_browser("https://www.nytimes.com/search?query=" + search_term)

# Find all the search result articles
articles = browser.find_elements("//ol[@data-testid='search-results']/li")


# Extract title, date, and description for each article and add to the list
for article in articles:
    # Extract the title
    title = article.find_element("//h4[@class='css-2fgx4k']")
    print(title)


# Close the browser window
browser.close_all_browsers()
```

Any assistance will appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In full disclosure, I'm the author of the [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) package. [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) is lightweight, less verbose extension of the Selenium web driver that makes browser automation even easier. Simply install the package with `pip install browserist` and try this:

```py
from browserist import Browser
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

search_term = "climate"

# with Browser() as browser:
    browser.open.url("https://www.nytimes.com/search?query=" + search_term)
    search_result_elements = browser.get.elements("//ol[@data-testid='search-results']/li")
    for element in search_result_elements:
        try:
            title = element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h4").text
            print(title)
        except:
            pass
```

Notes:

- The simpler search term `climate` will yield more, yet relevant results, e.g. `climate crisis`, but that's up to you to change.
- It's easier and more robust to target the title by the `h4` tag header instead of the the CSS token value that might be changed over time.
- As not all search result elements are uniform, I protect against breaking errors with the `try` and `except` clause.
- [Browserist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/browserist/) uses Chrome by default, and you can select other browsers, for instance Firefox, with a few changes:

```py
from browserist import Browser, BrowserType, BrowserSettings

...

with Browser(BrowserSettings(type=BrowserType.FIREFOX)) as browser:
```

Here's what I get, and I hope you find it useful. Let me know if you have any questions?

[image: Titles printed in the terminal]

[image: Results from NY Times]

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, the package work well however with this problem I'm supposed to use selenium under the rpaframework.

Comment: My pleasure, and you're welcome. In that case, I'm not sure you're using the `find_element` and `find_elements` methods correctly. You need to add the `By` selector as argument as well. For instance, something like this: `browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//ol[@data-testid='search-results']/li")`. Learn more here: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Comment: Thanks man, using `title = element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h4").text` works fine. I will recommend your package.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in the RPA framework, but have you considered simplifying your code to something like this? You probably only need to target the `h4` headline tags of the search results:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# After you get the search results with this command:
# browser.open_available_browser("https://www.nytimes.com/search?query=" + search_term)

title_elements = browser.find_elements(By.TAG, "h4")

for title_element in title_elements:
    print(title_element.text)
```

Disclaimer: I'm not sure the above code is working as I haven't tested it.

With the [Browserist](https://github.com/jakob-bagterp/browserist) package, I have tested it though, and you only need a few lines of code:

```py
from browserist import Browser
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

search_term = "climate"

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.open.url("https://www.nytimes.com/search?query=" + search_term)
    title_elements = browser.get.elements_by_tag("h4")
    for title_element in title_elements:
        print(title_element.text)
```

Here are the results I get in the terminal:

[image: Titles printed in the terminal]